# Recover byte string with invalid characters(UTF-8) after having decoded it in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, utf-8

I've logged a lot of texts that were being decoded to unicode(UTF-8) from a byte string.

Example:

From upstream I received a a lot of byte strings, like:

```
b_st = b'\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\xff\xfe\x00'
```

I saved those in my computer after doing a decoding

```
b_un = b_st.decode("utf-8", "replace")
```

As you can see the initial byte string have a invalid
characters to decode to UTF-8(e.g. `\xff`) so those will be replaced.

After that **I tried to recover the byte string** from that unicode text doing: `b_un.encode("utf-8")` but it **returns** to me **another byte string**, ****not the same** as the original.**

Is it possible to recover the original byte string?

PS. I didn't decode those texts intentionally, I didnt read the default behavior of an a Class that automatically converts any text to unicode if necessary.

Comment: original byte string is not text but JPEG image (see `JFIF` in bytes) and you shouldn't decode it. And `"replace"` may replace different bytes with the some byte and you can't encode this byte to different values.

Comment: yeah thats why i wanted to recover those images from utf-8, I wondered if exist something like a mapping from the known replaces to jpeg bytes to recover those images

Comment: I tested code and `"replace"` put always the same char with code `65533` (ie. in place of bytes `\xff`  and `\xd8` and `\xe0`) and you can't map `65533` back to `\xff`  and `\xd8` and `\xe0` at the same time. This image is lost.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`replace` is a lossy [codec error handler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.replace_errors), replacing any un-decodable bytes with `\ufffd` (the unicode replacement character)

as such it is impossible to recover your original image

If you're handed a byte string, you can write it to a file by using a binary io object:

```py
with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(byte_string)
```